# how to call FileHelpers.RecordTypeSelector correctly?

Tags: filehelpers

I'm working with FileHelpers: https://www.filehelpers.net/

I have a source file which contains a set of approximately 10 different RecordTypes. To accommodate, I intend to use a MultiRecordEngine (https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/).

As I read the instructions, I should declare the engine

```
var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof (Orders),
    typeof (Customer),
    typeof (SampleType));
```

... and then feed the "CustomSelector" ...

```
engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(CustomSelector);
```

Looking at the documentation at the link provided, "CustomSelector" is a private method inside Selector.cs.

```
private Type CustomSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
{
    if (recordLine.Length == 0)
        return null;
    if (Char.IsLetter(recordLine[0]))
        return typeof (Customer);
    else if (recordLine.Length == 14)
        return typeof (SampleType);
    else
        return typeof (Orders);
}
```

There's no mention of a delegate, and declaring one didn't improve Mister Compiler's opinion of my code. Does anybody have experience with MultiRecordEngine to tell me what perfectly obvious fact I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the documentation and my eyes were having a tiff. As given, this code...

```
engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(CustomSelector);
```

... is useful only if CustomSelector is a **local function**, which strikes me as bad form. I stuck with a separate Selector class, and declared "CustomSelector" as public static:

```
public static Type CustomSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
{
    if (recordLine.Length == 0)
        return null;
    if (Char.IsLetter(recordLine[0]))
        return typeof (Customer);
    else if (recordLine.Length == 14)
        return typeof (SampleType);
    else
        return typeof (Orders);
}
```

Once I tell MultiRecordEngine where to find it,

```
engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(Selector.CustomSelector);
```

... you're golden.

I hope this helps save the next person the 10 minutes I spent typing the question and answer. Enjoy! :)